# TWAIN video capturing

Tags: twain, twaindotnet, dynamic-web-twain

I tried to implement a video capture program in c# with TWAIN and a Leica DFC295 camera.

The problem I have is the Twain lib on internet only allows me to capture an image from the camera and is not able to capture the video directly from the camera.

Unfortunately I tried other technologies like Microsoft Directshow and the camera doesn't support those tools so it ends up not even able to select from the data source.

Is there any possible way to implement the video capture feature with TWAIN?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your 'capture video' mean? Recording the camera stream as a .mp4 or .avi video file?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. TWAIN can only capture images or a series of images but not video.